# Can't open Google Sites Apps Scripts anymore

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Sites:
- Go to "Manage Site"
- Click Google Apps Scripts
- (I have 2 scripts here)
- Click on one of the available scripts

A new tab opens with the error message: "A server error or bug occurred. If reloading the page doesn't help, please contact us."

What's wrong? How can I get Google to look at my problem?

The script itself is still working, just I can't view or edit it anymore.

https://sites.google.com/site/stamboomvanaken/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is [reported](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1675) to Google. Google works on it. Star this issue on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** *an even simpler (and better ) workaround has been posted on the issue trcker by martinkociman*

If you use Chrome you can get the ID of your script and insert this ID in the URL like this :

```
https://script.google.com/d/---------ID------------/edit
```

here is a screen capture of Chrome inspector, it worked for me on every gadgets ;-)

[image]